# Extracting a variable in Django / Python to display a live counting

Tags: python, django, jinja2

what i want is to have a "dynamic" counter (like a loading bar %) that counts up as the "prog" variable increases to 100

views.py:

```
...

qb = Client("http://www.on-demandlogistics.com:8080/")
    qb.login("admin", "adminadmin")
    qb.download_from_link(torrentLink)
    prog = 0

    while prog < 100:
        
        prog = int(float(qb.get_torrent("cca0bf46ce95c802e6a8f0e1f353978d12da6997")['total_downloaded'])
                   / float(qb.get_torrent("cca0bf46ce95c802e6a8f0e1f353978d12da6997")['total_size']) * 100)
        return render(request, "movies/dbsearch.html", {
                                "movie_name": "Downloading " + movie_name[0].title() + " now!", "progress": prog
                                    }
                          )
```

dbsearch.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>dbSearch</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>{{movie_name}}</h1>
<h2>{{progress}}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure how to have the number return live (ie count up with out hitting refresh) any information you could provide would be great

I'm a rookie at this stuff

Thanks,

littlejiver

Comment: A Template once rendered and the response sent to the requesting user is like a bullet fired from a gun. ;) Django no longer can do anything about it. What you need is to make an ajax  request using javascript.

Comment: thanks, I thought I might need to but if I could have avoided learn Javascript it would have been better lol